# How to replace a broken image URL given in attribute style background-image in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
<img  [src]="item.imgUrl" (error)="pictNotLoading($event)" alt="" />

pictNotLoading(event) { 
    event.target.src = '/assets/dynamic_images/medvibe_partner.png'; 
}
```

the above criteria will replace broken images. In my products listing page, I've decided to set `background-image` dynamically for each product item (as like hover effect).

```
<span class="product_thumbnail_hover" style="background-image:url('{{item.imgUrl}}');"></span>
```

But somehow I'm getting a bunch of broken image URLs from api call.
So, my question is how to replace a broken image url given in style background-image

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="item.imgUrl != null || item.imgUrl != undefined">
     <span class="product_thumbnail_hover" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': item.imgUrl ? 'url(' + item.imgUrl + ')' : 'url(' + '/assets/dynamic_images/prod_preview.png' + ')'}"></span>
</ng-template>
```

Above code resolved my issue temporarily. I don't know is this a good or worst method. think this might helps.